# Quantile function of $fx) = 3x^2 \cdot 1_{[0,1]}(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's define density function of random variable $X$ as:

$$f(x) = 3x^2 \cdot 1_{[0,1]}(x)$$

I want to find quantile function of variable $X$ in point $\alpha \in [0,1]$

**My work so far**

Quantile function is a reverse function to cumulative ditribution function, so in my opinion it's good to start with derivation of it.

Cumulative distribution function is given by formula:

$$F(x) =  \begin{cases}
0 & \text{for} \; x \in (-\infty, 0) \\
x^3 & \text{for} \; x \in [0,1] \\ 
1 & \text{for} \; x \in (1 , + \infty) 
\end{cases}$$

Now talking about quantiles - basing on function $F$ we see that quantile at level $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ is $(\alpha)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. I.e. $Q_\alpha(X) = \alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

However what happens when $\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha = 1$ ?

When $\alpha = 0$ then there is infinite number of points on which CDF takes value $0$. But because we want to calcualte quantile we are interested in infimum of such points. It meas that it will be equal to $-\infty$.

Applying some justification to $\alpha = 1$ we get that $Q_1 = 1$.

Ending with:

$$Q_\alpha(x) =  \begin{cases}
-\infty & \text{for} \; \alpha = 0  \\
\alpha^\frac 1 3 & \text{for} \; \alpha \in (0, 1) \\ 
1 & \text{for} \; \alpha =1
\end{cases}$$

Does my way of thinking make sense?

Comment: Your CDF should be $x^3$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: I adjusted my question - is it correct now?

Comment: $F_X(x) = x^3,$ for $0 < x < 1,$ as you say. Then quantile function is $F_X^{-1}(u) = u^{1/3},$ for $0 < u < 1.$